# How to exit the program after max 3 attempts using Python, for exception program , if you dont get the desired output?

Tags: python, exception

How to exit the program after max 3 attempts using Python, for exception program , if you dont get the desired output?

```
while True:
         try:
            x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
            break
         #except Exception as e:
         #     print (e)
         except ValueError:
             print ("You have entered the non-numeric value. Enter the numerical value.")
         except KeyboardInterrupt:
             print ("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
             exit (1)
```

Comment: As an aside to the main question, please keep your indentation standard - most people use 4 spaces [per PEP-8](https://realpython.com/python-pep8/), but you have used 9, 3 and 4 in different places.

Answer (score 3):

```
nothing = 0
while nothing < 3:
    nothing += 1
    try:
       x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
       break
         #except Exception as e:
         #     print (e)
    except ValueError:
        print ("You have entered the non-numeric value. Enter the numerical value.")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
c = 0
while c < 3:
     c += 1
     try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        break
     except ValueError:
         print ("You have entered the non-numeric value. Enter the numerical value.")
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print ("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
         break
```

Answer (score 1):

You want exit after 3 attemps. Try this and count that input is wrong:

```
num_err = 0
while num_err < 3:
    try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print ("You have entered the non-numeric value. Enter the numerical value.")
        num_err += 1
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sys.exit()` for stopping the whole script

```
import sys

while True:
     try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
     #except Exception as e:
     #     print (e)
     except ValueError:
         print ("You have entered the non-numeric value. Enter the numerical value.")
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
         print ("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
         sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I read all the code that is submitted above but one thing is missing, that if a user
`enter` two incorrect value  then `enter` a correct value after that he has only one chance. That is if user `enter` any wrong `input` after entering two correct `input` the loop will break.

So I have tried to solve this problem. Look at my code...

```
count = 0
while True:
    try:
        x = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        count = 0
        break
    except ValueError:
        count += 1
        print("You have entered the non-numeric value.Only three invalid inputs are allowed. Enter the numerical value.")

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("\nYou have press Ctr+C.")
        exit(1)
    if count == 3:
        break
```

I am trying to explain what I have written in this `code`.
As you have mentioned that a user can `enter` only three `invalid` `input` so I have increased the `variable` `count` each time when `user` will `enter` an `invalid` `input`. But if a `user` will `enter` a valid `input` then the `count` will be `0`. It means again the `user` can `enter` maximum three `invalid` `input`. After `entering` three `invalid` `input` continuously the `count` will be `3` and the `loop` `break`